# How can I add a horizontal line to datadog?

Tags: datadog

How do I add a horizontal red-dashed-line in the number 2.5 to this view?
I've added a marker with value 2.5 but it always show the line on the 0.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the line not being displayed properly was related to the unit. The view is displaying the values in `Gbyte`. The field within the Marker is in `bytes`.

I added `3000000000` instead of `3` and it worked fine.